# Auto deploy to nginx server on digital ocean using gitlab-ci.yaml

Tags: nginx, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

I am quite new to DevOps and I want to auto-deploy my react build folder to an Nginx server on digital ocean using gitlab-ci.yaml I have tried in auto-deploying nodejs backend in the base and it was quite easy but I don't know where to start or even what to do auto-deploying to Nginx using gitlab-ci without docker. Please I need help

Comment: Add an scp step in the gitlab-cli.yml file and copy the files to the required folder in the server.